# Error while doing apt-get update

Tags: 14.04

I always get stuck like this with sudo-apt get update. Can somebody help me with this and explain how to deal with such issues in general.

```
Ign http://dl.google.com stable InRelease
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease                                  
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                  
Hit http://dl.google.com stable Release.gpg                                    
Ign http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease                              
Hit http://dl.google.com stable Release                                        
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty Release.gpg                                
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                  
Hit http://dl.google.com stable/main amd64 Packages                            
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty Release                                    
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                  
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty/main Sources                               
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                  
Get:1 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates InRelease [65.9 kB]          
Get:2 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security InRelease [65.9 kB]           
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty/main amd64 Packages                        
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages                        
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty/main i386 Packages                         
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports InRelease                    
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                         
Get:3 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted Sources [4,064 B]  
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release.gpg                            
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en                        
Get:4 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted Sources [5,360 B] 
Hit http://http.kali.org kali-rolling InRelease                                
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages                        
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main Translation-en_IN                         
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main Translation-en                            
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                         
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en                        
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release.gpg                                
Hit http://http.kali.org kali-rolling/main amd64 Packages                      
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages                        
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                         
Get:5 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main Sources [121 kB]         
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en                        
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en_IN                     
Hit http://http.kali.org kali-rolling/contrib amd64 Packages                   
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release                                    
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en                        
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages                        
Get:6 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe Sources [44.3 kB]    
Hit http://http.kali.org kali-rolling/non-free amd64 Packages                  
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                         
Get:7 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse Sources [3,201 B]  
Hit http://http.kali.org kali-rolling/main i386 Packages                       
Get:8 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted amd64 Packages [13.0 kB]
Hit http://http.kali.org kali-rolling/contrib i386 Packages                    
Get:9 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main Sources [383 kB]        
Hit http://http.kali.org kali-rolling/non-free i386 Packages                   
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en_IN                     
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en                        
Get:10 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe Sources [169 kB]   
Get:11 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse Sources [7,511 B]
Get:12 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted amd64 Packages [15.9 kB]
Get:13 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main amd64 Packages [536 kB] 
Get:14 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe amd64 Packages [140 kB]
Get:15 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse amd64 Packages [5,198 B]
Get:16 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted i386 Packages [12.7 kB]
Ign http://http.kali.org kali-rolling/contrib Translation-en_IN                
Ign http://http.kali.org kali-rolling/contrib Translation-en          
Get:17 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages [905 kB]
Ign http://http.kali.org kali-rolling/main Translation-en_IN                   
Ign http://http.kali.org kali-rolling/main Translation-en                      
Ign http://http.kali.org kali-rolling/non-free Translation-en_IN               
Ign http://http.kali.org kali-rolling/non-free Translation-en                  
Get:18 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe amd64 Packages [387 kB]
Get:19 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages [15.0 kB]
Get:20 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main i386 Packages [497 kB]  
Get:21 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted i386 Packages [15.6 kB]
Get:22 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe i386 Packages [140 kB]
Get:23 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse i386 Packages [5,348 B]
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main Translation-en             
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse Translation-en       
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted Translation-en       
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe Translation-en         
Get:24 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main i386 Packages [865 kB] 
Get:25 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe i386 Packages [389 kB]
Get:26 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse i386 Packages [15.4 kB]
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main Translation-en            
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse Translation-en      
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted Translation-en      
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe Translation-en        
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted Sources           
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse Sources           
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main Sources                 
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe Sources             
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted amd64 Packages    
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse amd64 Packages    
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main amd64 Packages          
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe amd64 Packages      
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted i386 Packages     
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse i386 Packages     
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main i386 Packages           
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe i386 Packages       
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main Translation-en          
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse Translation-en    
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted Translation-en    
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe Translation-en      
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release                                
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Sources                     
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Sources                           
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Sources                       
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse Sources                     
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted amd64 Packages              
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main amd64 Packages                    
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe amd64 Packages                
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse amd64 Packages              
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted i386 Packages               
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main i386 Packages                     
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe i386 Packages                 
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse i386 Packages               
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en                    
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse Translation-en              
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Translation-en              
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Translation-en                
Ign http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en_IN                 
Ign http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse Translation-en_IN           
Ign http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Translation-en_IN           
Ign http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Translation-en_IN             
Fetched 4,828 kB in 35s (137 kB/s)                                             
Reading package lists... Done
W: Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package libapt-inst
W: Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package libapt-pkg
W: Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package libparse-cpan-meta-perl
W: Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package libjpeg62
W: Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package php-psr-log-implementation
W: Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package php-seclib
W: Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package php-sabre-http
W: Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package php-math-biginteger
W: Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package pypy-cffi
W: Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package pypy-cffi-backend-api-max
W: Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package pypy-cffi-backend-api-min
W: Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package python-cffi-backend-api-max
W: Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package python-cffi-backend-api-min
W: Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package python3-cffi-backend-api-max
W: Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package python3-cffi-backend-api-min
W: Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package libapt-inst
W: Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package libapt-pkg
W: Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package libjpeg62
W: Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package pypy-cffi
W: Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package pypy-cffi-backend-api-max
W: Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package pypy-cffi-backend-api-min
W: Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package python-cffi-backend-api-max
W: Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package python-cffi-backend-api-min
W: Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package python3-cffi-backend-api-max
W: Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package python3-cffi-backend-api-min
W: You may want to run apt-get update to correct these problems
```

Comment: Did you try sudo apt-get autoremove && sudo apt-get autoclean

Comment: yeah, didn't worked